# How do you go to the end of the line in emacs?

Tags: emacs

How do you go to the end of the line in emacs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use emacs, but I think it's Control-e.

Comment: If you use library [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el) then you can use a repeatable version of the command, `end-of-line+` (e.g., bind it to `C-e`). When you repeat it, it goes to the end of the next line, etc. There is also a repeatable version of `C-a`, `beginning-of-line+`.

Answer (score 11):

The <kbd>End</kbd> button works just fine, like always.  If you have no such key on your keyboard, the old Emacs standard keybinding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>, and knowing and using that makes it easier for the fingers to remember that <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> goes to the end of the current sentence, and <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> goes to the end of the current function.  But you don’t have to learn those if you don’t want to.

Comment: Unfortunately the end key on macs doesn't work in emacs

Comment: @Zubair: It works fine on my iMac; of course the keycap doesn’t say “End”, it says “↘”, and I run Debian GNU/Linux on it, not MacOS.